# pythonでcsvのデータを辞書型でPCにin memoryで格納したい

Tags: python, csv

おせわになります。
open w で下記の様に、csvを作りました

```
import csv

data = {'hito' : 61,'hiro' : 54,'yuto'  :  17,'osamu': 67,'keiko':71}

with open('name.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    fieldnamse = ['Name', 'Date']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file,fieldnames=fieldnamse)
    writer.writeheader()
    for name, key in data.items():
        writer.writerow({
        'Name': name,
        'Date': key
        })
```

結果は下記の通りです。

```
Name,Date
hito,61
hiro,54
yuto,17
osamu,67
keiko,71
```

今度、csvに保存したデータを、PCのメモリに格納したいのです。仮想メモリでも良いです。
下記の様にしました。

```
import csv
with open('name.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    print('Name','Date')
    d ={}
    for row in reader:
        print(row['Name'], row['Date'])
```

これでは、ただ、print文で、表示されるだけですし、row['Name'],  row['Date']を
一回だけメモリに格納するだけで、Loop中に書き換わってしまいます。

```
with open('name.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    print('Name','Date')
    d ={}
    for row in reader:
        A =row['Name']
        B =row['Date']
    return read_data`
```

A, Bのそれぞれに格納されるデータは、書き換わってしまいます。
配列の様なものを、本やWEBで検索していますが、見つかりません。
他のサイトで質問しても、高度な内容の回答しか届いていません。

```
　　read_data.append(row['Name']....)
```

の様な感じですが、appendは使用できません。
最後にreturnで、read_dataに格納されるイメージの方法を考えています。
あくまで、辞書形式で、pandasは使用しない方法を考えています。

結果として、上記のcsvのデータが、辞書データ、dataが入る事になりますが、メモリにデータを要求仕様通り、処理してから、open w あるいは、r+で変更する事が最終目標です、

classを使えば何とかやれそうなんですが、大掛かりになりそうなので、手が止まっています。
以上、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/157329

Answer (score 4):

辞書型の場合は、次のようにキーと値を指定すると追加・更新ができます。

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    d ={}
    for row in reader:
        d[row['Name']] = row['Date']
```

なお、辞書型の場合は、csvを使うよりもjsonを使うほうが相性がよく、次で書き込みが、

```
import json

data = {'hito': 61, 'hiro': 54, 'yuto': 17, 'osamu': 67, 'keiko': 71}
with open('name.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

次で、読み込みができます。

```
import json

with open('name.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。あっと言う読み込めるデータなのですね。驚きました。デバッグしようとしても、ステップ踏まないのですね。今度は、データを加工してから、書き込む事にチャレンジします。

Comment: csvのオープンについて書く場所を間違えました。最後の方に記載しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

pythonのライブラリの一つであるpandasを使用してよいのであれば、一行で書けます。

```
import pandas as pd #ここでエラーが出るならインストールが必要
pd.read_csv("name.csv").set_index("Name").to_dict()["Date"]
```

pandasではDataFrameというcsv的なデータをインメモリ的に処理できるクラスをサポートしており、pythonの基本的な辞書との相互変換もサポートしているので、このような風に簡単にできます。

Answer (score 0):

ご回答ありがとうございます。

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    d ={}
    for row in reader:
        d[row['Name']] = row['Date']with open('test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
```

で、最後に、`
       return d
で、一時的に、メモリに記憶する事が出来ました。
こんなに、簡単だとは、思いもよらなかったです。先程、classで、コードを書いて、一応成功しましたが、こちらの方が、遥かに良いです。

さて、jsonの件ですが、よく、APIのデータで、見かけます。pythonと相性が良いとは驚きです。
ただ、Win10にインストールしている、python3.6.xでは、dump()なるものが出てきません。
標準なのに不思議です。

どうも、ありがとうございました。`

Comment: Macでは、dump()が出て、test.jsonを作成出来ました。